# Computing $P(Z>0)$ with $Z\sim\mathrm{Skellam}(k;\lambda_1;\lambda_2)$

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, skellam-distribution

Given the variable $Z$, distributed as follows:

$Z\sim\mathrm{Skellam}(k;\lambda_1;\lambda_2)$

I would like to understand how to compute the probability $P$$(Z>0)$.

I know to compute the value $P$$(Z=z)$, by following what is described in the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) web page, but I do not understand how to compute the value of $P$$(Z>0)$, given the parameters $\kappa$, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

Since it is not a symmetric  distribution and, consequently, you cannot compute taht as follows:

$P$$(Z>0)$ $=$ $1-$$P$$(Z\leq0)$ $=$ $...$

I wonder how to compute $P$$(Z>0)$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know--and this is consistent with the Wikipedia page you quote--the Skellam family has only *two* parameters, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.  What does "$k$" represent?

Comment: Hi @whuber! $k$ is the value for which you compute the pmf. Probably I wrote down the question in a bad way.

Comment: Then "$k$" doesn't belong there at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is incorrect for you to say that you cannot compute $P(Z>0)=1-P(Z\leq 0)$.  This follows almost directly from probability axioms.  Rearranging that equation above, you can see that $P(Z>0) + P(Z\leq 0) = 1$, or the probability that $Z$ takes on a value above, below, or equal to 0 is 1.  This makes sense and does not rely on whether or not the distribution of $Z$ is symmetric.

What I would recommend doing is summing the Skellam pmf for $k=1,2,\ldots$ or $k=0,-1,-2,\ldots$ - whichever you find to be easier.  Note that the pmf of the Skellam distribution is $P(K=k)=\exp\{-(\mu_1+\mu_2)\}\left(\frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2}\right)^{k/2}I_k(2\sqrt{\mu_1\mu_2})$, where $I_k(\cdot)$ is the modified Bessel function.  (Credit: Wikipedia)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MattBrems and sorry for the trivial question! Now, everything seems to be clearer :)